# Theoretical : HTTP request to turn up volume in Windows?

Tags: windows, http, volume

I was wondering if there was a way to modify sound volume in Windows via an HTTP request, for use in a remote-control web-abb or something of the sort. I just think it'd be cool to be able to change the volume on my Windows machine from a website (or App) on my phone.

Has anyone ever heard of anything of this nature, or know if it is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this with just a straight HTTP connection to a Windows machine.

However, you could develop some type of helper/listening server and install it on the Windows machine that waits for a HTTP connection which could adjust the volume.

Comment: That's kind of what I meant, I guess I should have specified. Where could I look for more information about this type of thing? And is this going to be fairly language-limited or should it be possible on many languages? Thanks!